# Stub a method basing on arguments

Tags: mockito, stub

```
class ArgumentClass{
   int var;
}

class ClassMocked{
   int aMothod(ArgumentClass argumentClass){
      return anInt;
   }
}

class MyTest{
   Mock and Stub here
}
```

In MyTest, I want to stub aMothod such that it returns the value basing on value of ArgumentClass.var. And I have to do it in one go.
In other words, I have a test case where a moehod is called three times by the app code and basing on a variable in an argument object, I need different return values. I need to stub accordingly. Please let me know if there is a way.

Comment: You should provide some more information about the test you want and the expected result of the mocked method.  You could call, for example, `when(mock.aMethod(any())).thenReturn(1,2,3)` but I don't know enough about your scenafrio to know whether this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand that correctly you can do it in two different way with mockito. If you declare ClassMocked as a mock you should be able to say this:

```
when(mock.aMothod(eq(specificArgument))).thenReturn(1);
when(mock.aMothod(eq(anotherSpecificArgument))).thenReturn(2);
```

If you want to do it that regardless of the argument passed you want to return values based on the number of invocation of the method you can say:

```
when(mock.aMothod(any())).thenReturn(1, 2);
```

This says that when aMothod is called regardless of the parameter passed (any()) it will return in the first call 1 and when called second time it will return 2.

Comment: First solution depends on the `ArgumentClass` having an overridden `equals` method. Another solution would be to simply implement a custom `Matcher` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Though you can have your mock return values in the right order, as in [karruma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651527/1426891), you may also use an [Answer](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html) to calculate the mocked value:

```
when(mock.aMothod(any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Integer>() {
  @Override public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    ArgumentClass argument = invocation.getArguments()[0];
    return calculationBasedOn(argument);
  }
});
```

Or in Java 8 and Mockito 2 beta (untested, may need boxing/unboxing casts):

```
when(mock.aMothod(any())).thenAnswer(invocation ->
    calculatebasedOn(invocation.getArgumentAt(0, ArgumentClass.class)));
```

Though I have an anonymous inner class in the top sample, naturally, you can make a named Answer subclass and reuse it across your application.